# loopback-mongodb-connector modification to support slug ids

Tags: mongodb, model, slug, strongloop, loopbackjs

I want to use *slugs* (`String`) instead of `ObjectID` for some of my REST-exposed objects in *Loopback*

[What the docs says about model ids:](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Model+definition+reference#Modeldefinitionreference-ModelID)

> By default, if no ID properties are defined and the idInjection of the model options is false, LDL automatically adds an id property to the model as follows:

```js
id: {type: Number, generated: true, id: true}
```

I thought that I would just need to specify `String` as the type, and `generated: false` to avoid that loopback generates `ObjectId` instead.

```js
id: { type: String, generated: false, id: true },
```

--> This did not work at all

[In the code](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb), `mongodb.js` I see that whatever the name of my `id` is, it is wrapped with an `ObjectID` function, which explains the loss of `String` value.

*Side note : also, the* `generated` *property, is never used in mongodb connector code, what it is for?*

### My solution so far

Add a custom property (*objectId*, because I am not sure what *generated* is for) of my schema definition, which becomes :

```js
id: {
    type: String, 
    objectId: false, 
    id: true
},
```

I then use this property as following, in `MongoDB.prototype.create@mongodb.js:155` :

```js
var isObjectId = self.getDataSource(model)
                     .getModelDefinition(model)
                     .properties[idName]
                     .objectId;

if (idValue === null) {
    delete data[idName]; // Allow MongoDB to generate the id
} else {
    var oid = isObjectId ? ObjectID(idValue) : idValue; // Is it an Object ID?
    data._id = oid; // Set it to _id
    delete data[idName];
}
```

I updated `save()` method the same way, and now I can insert/modify objects with slug, and access them from the REST interface as well.

### Question

**I'm not sure this is right, will it break something?**

Also, I don't really like the idea of modifying dependencies, so I would prefer to use an official method, or write a pull request if you guys at *StrongLoop* think you can make use of this.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the following definition:

1. To set the string id on the client side

   ```
   id: { type: String, generated: false, id: true }
   ```

or

1. To use ObjectID as string

   ```
   id: { type: String, generated: true, id: true }
   ```

LoopBack mongodb connector tries to honor the id type. It only converts to ObjectID if the string format matches the ObjectID.

One bug was fixed recently but not released yet:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/15

Please let us know on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/loopbackjs if it doesn't for you.

Comment: I updated to 1.1.5 (from 1.1.4), and it broke my slug-ready API !! I am not surprised, because in both `create()` and `save()` methods (mongodb.js), `id` seem to be converted to `ObjectID` whatever the case, or I'm missing something :) Got it for the forum, I'll post there next time.

Comment: My bad, I did not see that ObjectID was not the same as mongodb function, hence it does not always return an Object ID. I will try to see what's wrong with my setup.

Comment: I got it, the update/upsert of the create/save object was not setting the _id in the data, leaving mongodb generate it. I sent a pull request.